# how to separate array with commas?

Tags: array

Let's say that i have this array:

Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 7 )

And this array is for example "print by `<?php print_r($_categories); ?>`

but now, how to make a array implode to this format: 13,7 (without comma after the last value)

Thanks,
nelson

Comment: This is a question for Stack Overflow. Also, you can easily search PHP impload. You get this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php  Try Google first. It works really well. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an inbuilt [PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$result = implode($input, ',');
```

(as noted by Brian's [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59740/how-to-separate-array-with-commas#comment77382_59740).

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'm going to move this question to Stack Overflow.